# Changing the colour of a row and the values in a cell depending on what you select in multiple dropdown menus

Tags: excel, menu, formatting, conditional-statements, dropdown

In the excel file that's found on this website:

https://frsecure.com/incident-response-log-template/

When you choose different options in the dropdown menus, it makes both the entire row change colour and it causes the cells in the "ITR Required" and the "Class" columns to change to "Yes/No" and "High/Medium/Low" respectively.

[The excel file in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIccr.jpg)

How would I go about writing the function and/or writing a rule to get this effect in my excel files?

Comment: I do not download any file from an unknown source, that's why I cannot answer based on that file. But, from what you explain, it uses a *conditional formating* based on a custom rule like `=$C1="A"` which is applied to a region. Just make sure that your reference (here $C1) is evaluated with regard to the **active** (usually first) cell of your selection. The fixed column ($) makes sure, that every column is colored if the given/fixed one features an "A". The second function seems to be simply based on an `IF` formula. If the cell with the dropdown features X, then the result should be Y.

Comment: And the drop-down can be done via *Data/data validation/list*